# how to create x,y pair from a list

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a list with `k` elements.
I want to form another list with `x,y` pairs where the `y` value is the element in the indices to the right of the `x` value.

For example:

I have a list with 4 elements: `4, 8, 7, 1`
I need to create a list of pairs with the pairs like this:
`(4, 8), (4, 7), (4, 1), (8, 7), (8, 1) (7, 1)`

I am using python here is my code:

```
list1 = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:k]
list2 = [(val,val1) for val in person1 for val1 in person2[1:]]
```

Comment: What is your *question*? You've provided code, but it is not a [mcve]

Comment: So what you are looking for is combinations. Take a look at `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1 = [4, 8, 7, 1]
list2 = [(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(list1) for y in list1[i + 1:]]
print(list2)  # [(4, 8), (4, 7), (4, 1), (8, 7), (8, 1), (7, 1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

You use [`combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from the built in module, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to do that:

```
from itertools import combinations

lst = [4, 8, 7, 1]

print(list(combinations(lst, 2)))
```

Output:

```
[(4, 8), (4, 7), (4, 1), (8, 7), (8, 1), (7, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do in this way:

```
l=[4,8,7,1]

result = [(l[i],l[j]) for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(i+1,len(l))]
```